# Dask.array.ghost attribute is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to use dask.array.ghost attribute to perform a filtering operation on an array of data but currently, that attribute no longer is supported are there any alternate library supporting this function feature?

```
     69         import dask.array as da
     70         if kernel != None:
     71             hw = tuple(np.array(kernel) // 2)
---> 72             darray = da.ghost.ghost(darray, depth=hw, boundary='reflect')
     73 
     74         return(darray, chunks_init)

AttributeError: module 'dask.array' has no attribute 'ghost'
```

Comment: The [GitHub PR removing it](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/4121#issue-225091639) is pointing to `dask.array.overlap` as replacement

Comment: The main entry to this was and remains `map_overlap` (plus `stencil`) - you are less likely to need the deeper functions.